# How to detect required XML attributes?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I have an XML content without defined attributes, like this:

```
<rootElement>
   <subElement1/>
</rootElement>
```

I want to populate this XML content with required attributes defined in XML Schema (XSD) for this XML.

For example, according to XSD subElement1 has required attribute 'id'.

What is the best way (for Java processing) to detect that and add such attributes to XML?
We need to add required attributes and set appropriate values for them.

As a result for example above we need to have the following XML:

```
<rootElement>
   <subElement1 id="some-value"/>
</rootElement>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use JAXB for that. Search the Internet for tutorials.

Steps to proceed further with JAXB,

1. Generate Java files using JAXB by providing the schema
2. Unmarshal your XML to generated Java classes (beans). Don't do validation or set validation handler here.
3. Populate those classes with appropriate values. `required` elements can be found using annotation look up. JAXB annotation for element would look like something, `@XmlElement(name = "ElementName", required = true)`. And an attribute annotation would be something similar to this, `@XmlAttribute(required = true)`
4. Marshal your bean back to XML. You can validate your bean using `ValidationHandler`, while marshalling. Below is the sample code snippet,

   ```
   marshller = JAXBContext.newInstance(pkgOrClassName).createUnmarshaller();
   marshller.setSchema(getSchema(xsd)); // skip this line for unmarshaller
   marshller.setEventHandler(new ValidationHandler()); // skip this line for unmarshaller
   ```

Comment: This is good way for static xml and xsd maybe. But I have to arrange the attributes on the fly in my code

Comment: @Nawa: Your xsd/schema is going to be fixed, most likely. But yes, XML can be any file adhering to that schema. But this will work for that, I believe. Otherwise, please elaborate the exact issue you are having.

Comment: Initial xml doesn't contain attributes in general, only tags there exists, it can be invalid over schema due to lack required attributes. I want to fill all required attributes in initial xml to make it valid.

Comment: @Nawa: That would be fine too. Don't set validation handler while unmarshalling, only do it for marshalling. I hope you are getting my point. I am also updating my post.

Answer (score 3):

In the XML schema definition, i.e. XSD file, attributes are optional by default. To make an attribute required, you have to define:

```
<xs:attribute name="surname" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
```

You will find a very good introduction on XML and XML Schema Definitions, i.e. XSD, on [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com).

In Java the equivalent of defining a XML schema is using JAXB, i.e. Java API for XML Binding that is included into Java SE. There you would define, e.g.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Person { public @XmlAttribute(required=true) String surname; }
```

Hope this could clarify your question.

Comment: I know how to define required attributes in XSD, but this is not my task. I just want to insert all required atributes in XML

Comment: Once you have JAXB classes, representing your XML entities, you can use Reflection to query annotations for required attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a DOM parser.Has methods to traverse XML trees, access, insert, and delete nodes

Comment: I know it. But how I find required attributes? I was watched SAX parser and didn't find how to do it.

Comment: Check this http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom-schema-validation.html. You activate validation and use error handlers...might be a solution

Comment: Yes, I had this idea just in case

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same idea of Cris but I think that with this validator you don't have information about the point in which you have had the error.
I think that you have to create or extend your own validator.